# How to define a 'const' that will hold the value of variable?

Tags: php

I don't know how exactly to name this question.
So, I have a class that has some properties like `$date`.
Next, in my method, I am making a loop with some calculations, and in each iteration I `$date->modify('+1 month');`
So, if the starting date was for example 01/01/2000, after 24 iterations it became 01/01/2002. 
But after this loop I have to call a another method with starting date(unmodified) but $this->$date gives me a modified date of 01/01/2002.
I tried to implement something like : after for loop to make a comeBack modifying, like `$date->modify("$duration * -1 . 'months' ");`, but in some specific cases, because project is already complex, it comes back for + - 1 month difference.

So, I tried on the beginning of the method to make smth like :

```
$newArray = [];
array_push($newArray,$this->date);
```

But anyway, it gives me a modified date :/

How can I make somewhere a variable that will hold the starting date, to can access this date from anywhere?

Like, defining a constant from a variable, and then just use it anywhere?

Comment: Can you post the class please?

Comment: You could use [`clone`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) to make a copy of the original `date` object. something like this, `$orig_date = clone $date;`

Comment: Use `DateTimeImmutable` - any modifications will return a modified copy, without affecting the original

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to keep the original, you should clone it instead of modifying it. Then you can add months to the clone in the loop.

```
$iterationDate = clone $date;
```

Now your original date will not change when you change the `$iterationDate`.